# \renewcommand\tablename{name} does not work

Tags: tables, floats, naming

I am completely noobie in LaTeX. I need to change table name in all captions. But when I write `\renewcommand\tablename{newname}` at the beginning of document, it doesn't do anything. It's still "Table" My code looks like this:

```
...
\renewcommand\tablename{new}
...
\begin{table}[b]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|l|}
... your table ...
\end{tabular}
\caption{This table shows some data}
\end{table}
...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you loading the `babel` package? With what languages?

Comment: \usepackage[slovak,english]{babel}

Comment: It works for me. Can you give a full MWE. What are the class and other package details?

Comment: @HarishKumar; as soon as you load `babel` with the options mentioned by the OP in his comment, the redefinition using just `\renewcommand...` in the preamble will not work.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: I have given the `\renewcommand.. after the `\begn{document}` and it works. How come????

Comment: @HarishKumar: yes; if you use it after `\begin{document}` it will work (see my answer using `\AtBeginDocument`); this is due to the inner works of babel, and its `\captions<language>` directive.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina: Thanks, I never used babel.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Since you are loading `babel`, the simple

```
\renewcommand\tablename{new}
```

in the preamble, will not work. You can use either of the following options after loading `babel`:

```
\AtBeginDocument{%
  \renewcommand\tablename{new}
}
```

or

```
\addto\captionsenglish{%
  \renewcommand\tablename{new}
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In Spanish, the solution is quite simple:

```
\usepackage[spanish,es-tabla]{babel}
```

does the trick.

I don't know in other languages, but I think `babel` will also have the trick.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This does do the job as long as you wish to use the translation provided by [`babel`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/babel) if you want to do something different [Gonzalo Medina's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/55099/106162) is required.

Comment: great answer, thanks !