# How to change the tablename and reflect also when using cleveref?

Tags: cleveref, polyglossia

I have the following example document where I'm using `polyglossia` and `cleveref`. The default name for *table* in spanish is *cuadro*. How can I change it into *tabla* and propagate this change to cleveref?

Here is what I tried:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{spanish}
\gappto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
%\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}
%\Crefname{table}{Tabla}{Tablas}
\begin{document}
Teste \Cref{tbl01}.
\begin{table}[h]
\caption{Teste.}
\label{tbl01}
\begin{tabular}{lll}
a & b & c \\
d & e & f \\
g & h & i 
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

I've also tried with the commented lines. In both cases, the result was:

[image]

Comment: As pointed out in the comments [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536894/cleveref-and-polyglossia-problems-with-crefname), you have to load cleveref before polyglossia. But then you miss all the translations…

Comment: Maybe you should use babel instead of polyglossia.

Comment: @NBur changing the order makes it even worse... instead of *Cuadro* you'll get *Table*.  The cleveref documentation also exemplifies loading babel before cleveref.

Answer (score 1):

It seems there are some incompatibilities between `polyglossia` and `cleveref` (see [this question and the comments](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536894/cleveref-and-polyglossia-problems-with-crefname)).

You can solve your problem with `babel`:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper, spanish]{article}
\usepackage{babel}
\addto\captionsspanish{\renewcommand{\tablename}{Tabla}}
\usepackage{cleveref}
\crefname{table}{tabla}{tablas}
\Crefname{table}{Tabla}{Tablas}
\begin{document}
    Teste \Cref{tbl01}.
    \begin{table}[h]
        \caption{Teste.}
        \label{tbl01}
        \begin{tabular}{lll}
            a & b & c \\
            d & e & f \\
            g & h & i 
        \end{tabular}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Note that the language is specified as an option of the document class.

[image]

Comment: Instead of redefining the `tablename` for spanish, I just found a very simple solution [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/341926/151808)! But you do need to use `crefname`.

Comment: I switched from babel to polyglossia... so I was looking for a solution still using polyglossia.